# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined after passing props. Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently fetching some data with and I'm trying to perform operations on some of the props of that data.

I'm trying to fetch my list students like this:

```
   const [studentDetails, setStudentDetails] = useState([]);
   const [collegeOpportunities, setCollegeOpportunities] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/v1/students/1022")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        setStudentDetails(response);
        setCollegeOpportunities(studentDetails.Opportunities)
        setIsLoading(false);    
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

and then, when I try to perform some operations on `collegeOpportunities`, I receive the error. The functions I'm trying to run are:

```
  const dropdownFilter = collegeOpportunities.filter(opportunity =>{
      return(
          opportunity.type.indexOf(dropdownValue) >= 0
      )
  })


  const filteredOpportunities = dropdownFilter.filter(opportunity => {
      return (
          opportunity.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
          opportunity.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0
      );
    });
```

on `collegeOpportunities.filter` I receive the `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

This seems like an async issue to me, like I'm tryng to access the `collegeOpportunities` before I've set them. Any suggestion from could it actually be or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```js
setCollegeOpportunities(studentDetails.Opportunities)
```

`setStudentDetails` updates the state asynchronously. So, `studentDetails` in the above line is not what you expect it to be. It's actually doing `[].Opportunities` which is `undefined`.

Try the following.

```js
setCollegeOpportunities(response.Opportunities)
```

Make sure the key `Opportunities` exists in the server response and is an array. Otherwise, you'll run into `TypeError`s when `filter`ing.

Comment: Thanks man. That explains a lot. Quite silly of me to try and load it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(collegeOpportunities || []).filter(...
```

Comment: doesnt work, it loads from am empty array and then what? It stays empty where it should try again whenever the props load...